# Guide to navigating template HTML in directive?

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone know of a definitive guide to navigating the html you use for a directive template?

When I console log `elem` (from `link:(scope,elem,attrs)`), it seems there are a lot more functions and attributes than detailed here with what jqlite can do:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

For example, there is a firstChild property, children, innerHtml, etc...

When I try to do something like `elem.children()[0].addClass("something")`, or `elem.firstChild.addClass("something")` it throws an `undefined is not a function` error even though `elem.children()[0]` or elem.firstChild can be logged to the console.

Comment: I want to say that elem is a dom element, and you might need to do something like $(elem).children() instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that `elem` is an angular element. However, `elem[0].firstChild` is of type `#text` and is not an angular element. Similarly, `elem.children()[0]` does not return an angular element.

So as a workaround, you can wrap your dom object in angular element by:

`angular.element(elem[0].firstChild)`

and now you can call `addClass` function on it.

Here's a basic [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AO2jYSKTBKzqKLkj9w4m?p=preview).